# Skaffold throws "error when deleting "STDIN": resource may not be empty". Why?

Tags: kubernetes, skaffold

I'm using Kubernetes and skaffold to manage my microservices.  This is a small snippet of my skaffold.yaml and k8s yaml:

`infra/k8s`

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test-gamification-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-gamification
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test-gamification
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: test-gamification
          image: test/gamification
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test-gamification-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: test-gamification
  ports:
    - name: test-gamification
      protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
```

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test-frontend-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-frontend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test-frontend
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: test-frontend
          image: test/client
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test-frontend-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: test-frontend
  ports:
    - name: test-frontend
      protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
```

`skaffold.yaml`

```yaml
apiVersion: skaffold/v3
kind: Config
deploy:
  kubectl: {}
build:
  local:
    push: false
  artifacts:
    - image: test/gamification
      context: gamification-service
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      sync:
        manual:
          - src: "src/***/*.ts"
            dest: .
    - image: test/client
      context: test-frontend
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      sync:
        manual:
          - src: "**/*.ts"
            dest: .
manifests:
  rawYaml:
    - ./infra/k8s/*
```

Whenever I run `skaffold dev`, I get the following error:

```
"error when deleting "STDIN": resource may not be empty".
```

I checked the kubernetes resources, but I don't see any.  So I'm a bit confused as to where this error is coming from.  I also tried restarting and stopping the kubernetes server in Docker Desktop, but that didn't work either.  My last hope is reinstalling everything, but want to see if there is another solution. Any advice would be much appreciated!